# Select Cell or Activate to the right of Selected Range - Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The problem with this function is that it also keeps selecting or activating the range that I just merged.  How can I do it to activate or select the cell to the right of my merged range without the merged range still be part of the selection/activation?

```
function mergeColumns(){
  
var app =SpreadsheetApp;
var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var first = activeSheet.getRange(11, 61).getValue();

    activeSheet.getRange(13,3,1,first).mergeAcross();
    activeSheet.getRange(13,3,1,first).offset(0, 1).activate();

}
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: An example would help a lot for people to understand

Answer (score 0):

If you are merging four cells, the next cell will be four columns away rather than one column away.

Increase the second parameter to `offset()` by as many clicks as necessary to reach the next cell.